# Drive API request sometimes returns an object another time an array - PHP

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I'm doing a little page that lists all files that are in google drive. In the first time I do the authentication and save the refresh token + user id and email and then I list all the files. To get the information I do this:

```
$result = array();
$pageToken = NULL;
do {
  try {             
    $parameters = array();
    if ($pageToken) {
      $parameters['pageToken'] = $pageToken;
    }

    $files = $service->files->listFiles($parameters);
    $list=$files->getItems();

    $result = array_merge($result,$list);
    $pageToken = $files->getNextPageToken();
  } catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
    $pageToken = NULL;
  }
} while ($pageToken);
```

And it works, but if the user refresh the page, I have do refresh the access token (getting the refresh token from db) and then proceed to do the same as above. In this case that code gives me an error because this time I get an associative array when I do:

```
$files = $service->files->listFiles($parameters);
```

To make it work I need to change the code to:

```
$result = array();
$pageToken = NULL;
do {
  try {
    $parameters = array();
    if ($pageToken) {
      $parameters['pageToken'] = $pageToken;
    }
    $files = $service->files->listFiles($parameters);
    $list=$files['items'];
    $result = array_merge($result,$list);
    $pageToken = $files['nextPageToken'];
  } catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
    $pageToken = NULL;
  }
} while ($pageToken);
```

This shouldn't happen but I have no idea what's wrong.

Comment: I guess there is something wrong with the library you are using to access GDrive. You might tell us how it is called. And please format your code properly when you post it on stackoverlfow.com .

Comment: This are the librarys I use, I downloaded them from google.

require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php';
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_DriveService.php';
require_once "google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_Oauth2Service.php";

I'm sorry, how do you wanna see the code formated?

Comment: I already did the formatting, plus added the php tag. (Obviously we're talking about php, so why not add it.) You should always do correct and consisten indention. Consistent is the important term here. For example, your first line started on column 8, and your second continued on column 4. Bad formatting is bad because the nice person who tries to help you will have a harder time reading your code. (And it does not matter if you indent with two or four white spaces, or even with `\t`. It just has to be consistent.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the relevant php source of the class, I guess I found what makes you trouble.
Look at [`Google_DriveService.php`](http://code.google.com/searchframe#FAxor0S6hu0/trunk/src/contrib/Google_DriveService.php&q=listFiles%20package%3agoogle-api-php-client%5C.googlecode%5C.com&l=119):

```
// ~Line 119
public function listFiles($optParams = array()) {
  $params = array();
  $params = array_merge($params, $optParams);
  $data = $this->__call('list', array($params));
  if ($this->useObjects()) {                       // THIS CALL HERE
    return new Google_FileList($data);
  } else {
    return $data;
  }
}
```

It checks if you want to work with objects, or not: `$this->useObjects()`.
This method is defined in the super class, [`Google_ServiceResource.php`](http://code.google.com/searchframe#FAxor0S6hu0/trunk/src/service/Google_ServiceResource.php&q=ServiceResource%20useObjects%20package%3agoogle-api-php-client%5C.googlecode%5C.com&l=180):

```
// ~Line 180
public  function useObjects() {
  global $apiConfig;
  return (isset($apiConfig['use_objects']) && $apiConfig['use_objects']);
}
```

This tells me, that when you configure your service, you will have to set `'use_object'` to `true`.

Comment: Glad to hear, yet your work isn't done here: You should mark an answer as solved, if it solved your problem. To do this, just click the tick below the voting of answers.

Comment: Thank you, I'm new here and I didn't know that :)